# How to push a string onto an array as a named object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How would I transform the array in imageCollection to get the array in carouselPhotos? (See code below).

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  
state = {
      imageCollection: [
            {
            name: "Pictures of birds"
            image1: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1A.jpg", 
            image2: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image2A.jpg",
            image3: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image3A.jpg"}
],
      carouselPhotos: [
      {
        image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1A.jpg", 
      },
      {
        image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image2A.jpg",
      },
      {
        image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image3A.jpg",
      },
    ],
  };
```

I am using the react-native-snap-carousel, which renders 1 carousel card per object, so each image must be its own object. It is also important that the data in carouselPhotos is labeled as 'image', and it must be loaded for when the page opens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Clarifications:
imageCollection has many objects, but I will just pick one object for the carouselPhoto. There are three image properties names imageX, but there are also other properties such as "name"

Comment: Is imageCollection always an array with only one object? Are the properties always named `imageX`?

Comment: imageCollection has many objects, but I will just pick one object for the carouselPhoto. There are three image properties names imageX, but there are also other properties such as "name"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply retrieve the values from your `imageCollection` object, then map them to the desired format.

```
Object.values(state.imageCollection[0]).map(imgUrl => ({ image: imgUrl }));
```

#### EDIT

Since the object in your `imageCollection` array contains keys that should be ignored, we can first filter them out before mapping to the transformed result. We filter out keys that do not begin with the string "image", using [`Array.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). This means we also need to gather the keys from the object along with the values, so we use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(state.imageCollection[0]).filter(([key, val]) => key.startsWith("image")).map(([key, val]) => ({ image: val}));
```

Try it out:

```js
state = {
  imageCollection: [
    {
      name: "Pictures of birds",
      image1: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1A.jpg", 
      image2: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image2A.jpg",
      image3: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image3A.jpg"
    }
  ]
}

const result = Object.entries(state.imageCollection[0])
                .filter(
                  ([key, val]) => key.startsWith("image"))
                .map(
                  ([key, val]) => ({ image: val}));

console.log(result);

state.carouselPhotos = result;
console.log(state);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! One slight issue:
The array imageCollection contains other properties (such as name). I've since amended the question.  However, there will only ever be three pictures.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the keys of interest look like "imageX", where X is any number (e.g. 3, 07, 25)?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to assume that. I am actually pulling the data from a database, so it will be formatted exactly like that.

Comment: In that case, see the edit. Please let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` & inside the callback iterate the current object and create a new object for each image and push it to the accumulator array

```js
const imageCollection = [{
  image1: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1A.jpg",
  image2: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image2A.jpg",
  image3: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image3A.jpg"
}]


const carouselData = imageCollection.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    acc.push({
      image: curr[keys]
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(carouselData)
```